# NoSQL or SQL database for thousands of rows / items in array every day?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, space

I would like to keep data about number of views of cca 2.000 videos per day in DB. But let's say I would like to keep the data from the whole year. It would then be 730.000 rows in SQL DB, which I guess is enormous. In NoSQL DB I would then still have e.g. 2.000 objects with some array[365], which is much more fast for processing I guess? What do you think?

Comment: 730,000 rows is trivial for a modern RDBMS. Loading that number of rows per hour wouldn't be a particularly challenging workload if the DBMS was appropriately specified

Comment: Are you going to run it on your phone?

Comment: @jarlh no it will be a .NET desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL database like postgres.  Postgres is faster for processing because of sql support and indices

730k is nothing btw

Comment: I have never had that much data in DB before. So I just want to be careful and don't make a choice mistake right at the beginning of developing the app. I want to then read the data from the DB and make some statistics in the app. I am worried it takes to much time to get the data from DB (reading so many rows - almost 1 milion -  seems as a long task to me). Do you have some professional experience?

Comment: The number of records in a database is pretty irrelevant - unless you are trying to query them all in one go. It is much more important to design your database properly so that it performs well (tables + indexes, partitioning, etc). FYI I support databases that hold billions of records and most user queries run in a few seconds